# How to extract digit from an integer that fits a range of numbers?

Tags: c++, loops

For example, a user might input an ID number and creating a function that goes through that ID number and extracts and prints the first number that fits between 3 and 8?

E.g.

1. They input a ID "157567658" , this function would go through and extract 5 only as its the first digit to be within that range (3-8)

Comment: Can you tell what is the question?

Comment: The question is _can you do my homeworks_?

Comment: Input and process as a string of characters.  The _"integer"_ in the question is just to put you off.

Comment: what did you try? what are you missing to write that function?

Comment: imho you should not use tags to anticipate possible answers. There is no loop in your question, so why did you tag it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on a comment, an integer is not necessarily an `int`. For example

```
char five = '5';
```

is an integer stored in a `char`. Also

```
std::string x = "157567658";
```

are several single digit integers represented as a `std::string`.

The ingredients you need are:

- Read user input into a `std::string`:

```
    std::string id;
    std::cin >> id;
```

- Loop over all characters in a `std::string` :

```
    for (const char& c : id) {
        // c are the elements of id
    }
```

- Pick the digit you are looking for

```
    if ('3' <= c && c < '8') {   // half-open ranges are most common
        // do something with c
    }
```

You just have to put things together.